# Select * from SQLite TempTable not working properly

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset, temp-tables

I have this small piece of code, the scope is:
In the outter while: I calculate a "min" number (selected from the tempTable)
In the inner while: I "Select * from (tempTable) where (some conditions)" (im completly sure there is more than 1 row that matches these conditions) and then i update the min in each row selected (whithin other aspects not relevant)

```
 The inner while is conditioned by rs.next() which (as it does in other parts of my code) it should iterate through every row that matches the condition ("Select * from (tempTable) where (some conditions)")

  Basically the program should work as: getting a "min" value, then proceed to update each row with equal "min" and "min" = "min" + 1. So in the next iteration of the outter while the "min" should be 1 more.
  Instead, what it does is: get "min" value, then update ONLY the first row that matches that min value and goes back to the outter while(which calculates the min again). In the end, the output is rather the same and it kinda works, but I would really appreciate if it worked as I intended to match other aspects of the program.
  I think the problem comes from doing a select * from a TEMPtable which for some reason returns only 1 row (i've been investigating but couldnt find other people with the same issue, so i don't really know). As I mentioned, there is other parts of my code where I do the same select * NORMALtable and the ResultSet.Next() works as intended.

while( total_tfgs > 0 ) {
        int tfgs_round = 0;
        min = prepareStatement.executeQuery("SELECT MIN("+ PROFESORES_COL_TFGS +") FROM TEMP_TABLA_PROFESORES WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_OBLIGA + " = 'SÍ'").getInt(1);
        ResultSet rs = prepareStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLA_PROFESORES WHERE " + PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + " = '" + min + "' AND " + PROFESORES_COL_OBLIGA + " = 'SÍ'");
    
        while(rs.next()) {
            prepareStatement.executeUpdate("UPDATE TEMP_TABLA_PROFESORES SET PROFESORES_COL_TFGS = PROFESORES_COL_TFGS + 1 WHERE PROFESORES_COL_ID = '" + rs.getInt(1) + "'");
            tfgs_round = tfgs_round + 1;
            
            
        }
        
        total_tfgs = total_tfgs - tfgs_ronda;
    }
```

Here i place code where it works as i want it to work:

```
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsA = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_ALUMNOS);
    while(rsA.next()) {                
            String idA = String.valueOf(rsA.getInt("ALUMNOS_COL_ID"));
            String dniA = rsA.getString("ALUMNOS_COL_DNI");
            String nombreA = rsA.getString("ALUMNOS_COL_NOMBRE");
            
            String dataA[] = {idA, dniA, nombreA};
            DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel) table_Alumnos.getModel();
            
            tblModel.addRow(dataA);
            table_Alumnos.setModel(tblModel);
    }
```

PD: while redacting this i changed some variables to english (in the first code snipet) so it would be more legible(tfgs_round,total_tfgs), so if there is some misspell or something, thats not the problem. Please focus in the ResultSet select * from TEMP_TABLE (which i didnt change)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Christopher figured out what the problem was in an Answer below, thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call executeUpdate within the loop that is reading the ResultSet. That means you are using the statement for a second query while it is still involved in the first query. I would finish the first query entirely, close the ResultSet and then perform the update separately. If you really need to do an update while reading a ResultSet, I would build a new statement for it.

Comment: Works like a charm buddy ^^. Very much thank you.
**The problem was:** That I was using the same Statement to fill the ResultSet with the rows i wanted to update and to Update those rows, and that created a conflict. Simply using another Statement for the Update and it works perfect now.